# click baidu map marker and get infomation related to the marker

Tags: android, baidu

I'm using baidu map developing an andriod app.I upload my map data to baidu,and then get data using local search:

```
 CloudManager.getInstance().init(this);
 NearbySearchInfo info = new NearbySearchInfo();
 info.ak = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
 info.geoTableId = xxxxxx;
 info.radius = 30000;
 info.location = App.getLocation().getLongitude()+","+App.getLocation().getLatitude();
 CloudManager.getInstance().nearbySearch(info);
```

and then callback to show data on the map:

```
 @Override
public void onGetSearchResult(CloudSearchResult cloudSearchResult, int i) {
    if (cloudSearchResult != null && cloudSearchResult.poiList != null
            && cloudSearchResult.poiList.size() > 0){
        BitmapDescriptor bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_gcoding);
        LatLng ll;
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        for (CloudPoiInfo info : cloudSearchResult.poiList) {
            ll = new LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude);
            OverlayOptions oo = new MarkerOptions().icon(bd).position(ll);
            map.addOverlay(oo);
            builder.include(ll);

        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        MapStatusUpdate u = MapStatusUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds);
        map.animateMapStatus(u);
    }
}
```

After showing markers on the map,I want to click a marker and get data related to the marker.

Is it available? I cannot find out any answers,are there any solutions that work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get it solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
new MarkerOptions().icon(bd).position(ll).snippet("Information of place");
        map.addOverlay(oo);
```

Comment: It's not what I want, it's like [this](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1bodCiZX). And it's just nearbysearch function not POI search. POI search cannot use my map information.

Comment: @Uphie: Did u get the answer for your question? Can you please post your answer code snippet as your answer.